# Replace value of a property in properties file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file with code snippet :

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (file.properties) DO (
IF "%%A"=="StoreNumber" (
echo Updating value of StoreNumber. Enter value
SET /p VAR1= 
set [%%B]=!VAR1! 
rem echo %%A=!VAR1! >> file.properties
))
ENDLOCAL
```

I have properties file as : 
    StoreNumber=5655
(and many other properties)

Expected output:
StoreNumber=7373 .

Issue Facing : unable to replace 5655 with 7373.

Comment: dont mark it as duplicate bcoz i want replacement with a user entered number. Also the number i want to replace is not previously known

Comment: just adding a new line to  the file doesn't replace the original line or touch it in any other way. You have to rewrite the whole file.

Comment: [use the search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+ini+file+edit)

Comment: this is not the only property whose value need to be changed there are some 5-6 property values. and everytime rewriting the whole isnt a good idea